# Splitting one view model across multiple forms on one page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I've got an ASP.NET MVC 5 app that uses more of an MVVM approach to MVC: it has "view models" (VM) for the Entity Framework models.

***Our scenario:***

- We have a VM with an accompanying edit view with about 7 Bootstrap tabs.
- Each tab contains its own `@using (Html.BeginForm(...)) { ... }`.
- When the user switches tabs, we use AJAX to save its data (if it's valid).

***Our challenge:***

The POST `Edit(...)` action expects common hidden forms to be submitted with each AJAX call. We end up having duplicate hidden fields, as they're repeated for each form:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChildVm.Application_No) 
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChildVm.FormSubmitted)
// other hidden fields...
```

We run into issues when setting some of these fields, some of whose values are unique to each form. Because we're breaking HTML rules by having duplicate IDs, we have to use some ugly tricks to set their values in jQuery:

```
// Razor helper method to fetch ASP.NET ID for control
var formSubmittedId = '@Html.ClientIdFor(m => m.ChildVm.FormSubmitted)';

// Tab change handler
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var form = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href');
    var formId = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href').replace('#', '');
    var previousTab = $(form + '-form');
    $(previousTab).find('#' + formSubmittedId).val(formId);
    //....
});
```

The above works but it's ugly. How do you include form fields from the same view model across multiple forms on the same CSHTML without duplicate IDs? If I give the fields different IDs, wouldn't that break the Edit's POST action, which uses the IDs from the client to match them to their respective properties in the view model server side?

Thanks.

Comment: posts look at the NAME of the field not the ID.. for example `<input id='foo' name='bar' type='text'/>` would include `bar` in the formdata and not `foo`

Comment: Why do you even need to use Ids?  If two different forms have the same `name="ClientId"` and they are literally the same `ClientId` and it changes wouldn't you want both to change?  `$([name=clientid]).val(newid)`

Comment: Thank you, guys. Forgotten that forms submit NAME not ID. Now a follow-up: Can you have forms on the same page with the same field NAME?

Comment: You can have duplicate name `attributes` (only duplicate `id` attributes are invalid). And you do not need any scripts for this - you can just remove the `id` attribute using `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.yourProperty, new { id = "" })`. But the fact you repeating those inputs suggests your design is wrong anyway.

Comment: Thanks, @StephenMuecke. What's a better design for this?

Comment: Its not clear why you even need those hidden inputs (your just opening yourself up to malicious users) and you should just be getting those values again in the POST method if you need them. But if you really do want them, you only need one copy of them anyway (not inside a form) since your making ajax calls to post the data (you can serialize the relevant form, and append to it the serialized inputs by using the `.serialize()` method

Comment: Thanks, @StephenMuecke. I know it's beyond the scope of this question, but what's a safer way to have some fields stored on the client? These could be primary key fields needed server side to know what record to update in the POST edit action. Looking for best practices.

Comment: If its just the PK then that is necessary (and you can check that the user does have the permission to edit the record with that ID).

Comment: Thanks, @StephenMuecke. If you can, please throw your thoughts into an answer and I'll give you some credit :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153722/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-alex).

Comment: Can we continue tomorrow, @StephenMuecke? It's pretty late here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms post back the name/value pairs of its successful form controls, not the value of their `id` attributes. The only purpose of `id` attributes is for use in javascript/jquery and css selectors.

To prevent the invalid html (duplicate `id` attrbutes), you an just remove the attribute using (no *ugly* scripts required)

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChildVm.Application_No, new { id = "" })
```

However in general, you should avoid hidden inputs in your view (except for those related to the ID of your record, although that value is better added as a route value to your  anyway). If you need the values of your other hidden inputs in the POST method, then your should be getting your record again based on the ID.

If for some reason, you do need to post back all those additional values in each ajax post, a better solution would be to include those inputs once only inside a separate `<form>` element and use the `.serialize()` method to combine the values, for example

```
<form id="hiddeninputs">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChildVm.Application_No)
    .... // other hidden inputs
<form>
@using (Html.BeginForm(....))
{
    .... // form controls for 1st tab
}
@using (Html.BeginForm(....))
{
    .... // form controls for 2nd tab
}
```

and then in the script to post the form

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var formdata = $(this).serialize() + '&' + $('#hiddeninputs').serialize;
    $.ajax({
        ....
        data: formdata,
        ....
    });
    return false; // cancel the default submit
```

You could even remove the hidden inputs altogether, and construct a object to post back

```
var hiddeninputs = {
    'ChildVm.Application_No': '@Model.ChildVm.Application_No',
    ....
}
```

and use

```
var formdata = $(this).serialize() + '&' + $.param(hiddeninputs, true);
```

Comment: Thanks, @StephenMuecke. In the above, should the `_` be a `+` when setting `var formdata`?

Comment: Also, the custom object needs quotes around `ChildVm.Application_No`, otherwise gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` error.

Comment: Fat fingers :) - and needs to be quoted only if its a complex property name - i.e. contains a `.`